# Why would this snippet of code keep getting the error, "illegal start of expression" the error points to the & symbol

Tags: java

The problem is when the user inputs a number bot in between 111111 and 999999 a message comes up that says it must be between the two numbers.

```
  if (stockNumber < 111111) & (stockNumber > 999999);
  {
    System.out.println("Your first input must be between 111111 and 999999.");
  }
```

Comment: The format for `if` is `if (<expression>)`.  You have `if <expression>`.

Comment: (And, as others have pointed out, you probably should have `||`, not `&`.)

Comment: Also, you probably do not want the `;` at the end of the `if` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrong operator and parentheses formatting for the conditional.  Conditional also shouldn't have semicolon before its curly brackets.

```
if (stockNumber < 111111 || stockNumber > 999999) {
    System.out.println("Your first input must be between 111111 and 999999.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
if ((stockNumber < 111111) || (stockNumber > 999999)) {
    System.out.println("Your first input must be between 111111 and 999999.");
}
```